# How can I center a background image without loosing its quality?

Tags: html, css

The slide div is part of a carousel with images that are different in size or aspect ratio. How can I center the background image whatever the sizes might be without losing its quality? The code that I wrote is perfect for a normal size image, but if the image is smaller (30px by 30px) it will be stretched to match the div's width or height.

```
<div class="slide"></div>

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('./assets/img4.jpeg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a container (`.imagecont`):

```css
.container {
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.imagecont {
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 10em;
  max-height: 10em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagecont">
    <img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico">
  </div>
  <div class="imagecont">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Version with variable width (try resizing the container with mouse)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 5em;
  resize: horizontal;
  -moz-resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imagecont {
  position: relative;
  height: 10em;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagecont">
    <img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico">
  </div>
  <div class="imagecont">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you it worked! but do you know why it does not work with %?

Comment: @MedveTheFab, Where do you want to use %?